# Google Maps Click Event to move the marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using google maps to get the coordinates from user and it is working fine with dragging the marker but i need to change it with click event. I've tried "click" instead of "dragend" on

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(a)
```

which did not worked

My code is

```
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $villa['loc']; ?>);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: latlng,
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    title: 'move and pin exact point of your property',
    draggable: true
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(a) {
    var result = a.latLng.lat().toFixed(4) + ', ' + a.latLng.lng().toFixed(4);
    $('#loc').val(result);
    });
```

I receive the first marker position from DB. User can change the position by moving the marker and i get the updated result to write into DB. Dragging is working but "Click" is not. Any help is appreciated.

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

Comment: There is no click listener in the posted code.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution

```
        <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $villa['loc']; ?>);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: latlng,
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    title: 'move and pin exact point of your property',
    draggable: true
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(a) {
    var sonuc1 = a.latLng.lat().toFixed(4) + ', ' + a.latLng.lng().toFixed(4);
    $('#loc').val(sonuc1);
    });

                function placeMarker(location) {
                if ( marker ) {
                marker.setPosition(location);
                } else {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                map: map,
                title: 'move and pin exact point of your property'
                });
                }
                }

                google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
                placeMarker(event.latLng);
                var sonuc2 = event.latLng.lat().toFixed(4) + ', ' + event.latLng.lng().toFixed(4);
                $('#loc').val(sonuc2);
                });

    });


    $("#il").change(function() {
    var val = $('#il option:selected').val();
    var sonuc3 = (val);
    $('#sonucx').html(sonuc3);
    var mappos = document.getElementById("il").options[document.getElementById("il").selectedIndex].getAttribute('latLng');
    var latlngStr = mappos.split(',', 2);
    var lat = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]);
    var lng = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]);

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: latlng,
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    title: 'pin exact point of your property',
    draggable: true
    });

    var sonuc4 = lat + "," + lng;
    $('#loc').val(sonuc4);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(a) {
    var sonuc6 = a.latLng.lat().toFixed(4) + ', ' + a.latLng.lng().toFixed(4);
    $('#loc').val(sonuc6);
    });

                function placeMarker(location) {
                if ( marker ) {
                marker.setPosition(location);
                } else {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                map: map,
                title: 'move and pin exact point of your property'
                });
                }
                }

                google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
                placeMarker(event.latLng);
                var sonuc5 = event.latLng.lat().toFixed(4) + ', ' + event.latLng.lng().toFixed(4);
                $('#loc').val(sonuc5);
                });



    });
    </script>
```